# MYSQL WHERE clause is wrong value

Tags: php, mysql, where-clause

Whenever I try to perform my query, It gives me an unknown column error, because it is using my variable as the column name.

essentially

```
$search="lname";
$term="asdas";
```

(both of those are variables from a form on another page)

I run this:

```
if (isset($term))
    {
    $query = "SELECT * FROM test 
    WHERE $search = $term ";
    }
else
    {   
    $query = "SELECT * FROM test";
    }
echo $query;    
$result=mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
```

and then I get this as my error:
Unknown column 'asdas' in 'where clause'

Answer (score 2):

You need to enclose the search term in single quotes(also use mysql_real_escape_string to avoid any issues with quotes in the search string.).
i.e:

```
if (isset($term))     
{     
    $query = "SELECT * FROM test WHERE $search = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($term) . "' ";     
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to quote it.

```
if (isset($term))
    {
    $query = "SELECT * FROM test 
    WHERE $search = '$term' ";
    }
else
    {   
    $query = "SELECT * FROM test";
    }
echo $query;    
$result=mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
```

#### Other comments

It is always better to use parameterized queries if the driver supports it. It will prevent SQL injection.  As it stands, someone could send in a string "' or ''='" and the query turns out to be

```
SELECT * FROM test WHERE col1 = '' or ''=''
```

which is really benign but unexpected behaviour.  If the string contains single quotes, it also breaks your query (input is "o'neil")

```
SELECT * FROM test WHERE col1 = 'o'neil'   # << unmatched quotes
```

So, at the very least use `mysql_real_escape_string` if you cannot use parameters, i.e.

```
    $query = "SELECT * FROM test 
    WHERE $search = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($term) . "' ";
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to quote your `$term` parameter:

```
// protect from trivial sql injection attacks.
$term = mysql_real_escape_string("adas");
$query = "SELECT * FROM test 
    WHERE $search = '$term'";
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to surround the `term` value with quotes:

```
SELECT *
FROM test
WHERE lname='asdas'
```

otherwise any SQL server out there will think `asdas` is a field name and try to find it in the table.

Answer (score 1):

Add `'` around your columns

`$query = "SELECT * FROM test WHERE $search = '$term' ";`

Answer (score 1):

you need to put single quotes around $term so that the SQL thinks it's a string

Answer (score 1):

put single quote string always be quoted. Do not forgot use `mysql_real_escape_sring()`

```
 $query = "SELECT * FROM test 
    WHERE $search = '$term' ";
```

Answer (score 1):

Put single quotes around $term

if (isset($term))
{
$query = "SELECT * FROM test WHERE $search = '$term'";
}
else
{
$query = "SELECT * FROM test";
} 
echo $query;
$result=mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());